# Problema com scripts na Functions Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

olá estou com problema com o *functions.php* do **wordpress** ao registrar um script do **bootstrap**  ele não reconhece a sintax `wp_enqueue_script` e me manda o seguinte erro:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "wp_enqueue_script" in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\george\functions.php`

No seguinte código:

```js
<?php 
 
    function george_wp_styles(){

        wp_enqueue_style('style_css', get_stylesheet(  ) )


        wp_enqueue_script('boot1_js', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js')
        wp_enqueue_script('boot2_js','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js')
        wp_enqueue_script('boot3_js','https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js')

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'george_wp_styles');
```

Answer (score 2):

Está faltando `;` após `wp_enqueue_style` e `wp_enqueue_script`.